# Функция поиска из таблицы

Tags: html, jquery

Как реализовать поиск(функцию) по полю Mo_id чтобы не все данные отображались в таблице, а только то, что ищем. В данном случае у меня отображаются все данные из таблицы.

`id="search_bd_id"` – ссылка которая показывает все данные из таблицы(при нажатии)

`id="search1"` – окно в которые должны вносится данные для поиска

**_header.jsp**

```
 ...
 Search1 <input id="search1" name="search">
 <a href="t_moList" id="search_bd_id" onchange='search_bd()'>Search T_mo</a>
 ...
```

**t_moListView.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>T_mo List</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <jsp:include page="_header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <jsp:include page="_menu.jsp"></jsp:include>

    <h3>T_mo List</h3>

    <p style="color: red;">${errorString}</p>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" >
       <tr>
          <th>Mo_id</th>
          <th>Mo</th>
          <th>Mo_code</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
       </tr>
       <c:forEach items="${t_moList}" var="t_mo" >
          <tr>
             <td>${t_mo.mo_id}</td>
             <td>${t_mo.mo}</td>
             <td>${t_mo.mo_code}</td>
             <td>
                <a href="editT_mo?mo_id=${t_mo.mo_id}">Edit</a>
             </td>
             <td>
                <a href="deleteT_mo?code=${t_mo.mo_id}">Delete</a>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </c:forEach>
    </table>

    <a href="createT_mo" >Create T_mo</a>

    <jsp:include page="_footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
  Hello <b>${loginedUser.id}</b>
 </body>
</html>
```

Таблица T_mo List с полями
HTML

```
<tbody><tr>
          <th>Mo_id</th>
          <th>Mo</th>
          <th>Mo_code</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

Как можно реализовать данную функцию

```
<script>
function search_bd(){

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать [DataTables](https://datatables.net), это довольно тяжеловесное решение, но там реализовано очень много всего полезного для подобных задач.